# Slack Block Kit error: actions.block is Rejected: API not ok dispatch_failed

Tags: slack

I am encountering an error message in my Slack Block Kit implementation, and I am seeking assistance on Stack Overflow to resolve it. The error message I am receiving is "0c0d283b-1682782786.601 blocks.actions is REJECTED: API not ok dispatch_failed gantry-shared.35a0086.min.js?cacheKey=gantry-1682734094:60  This error occurs when I click on a button in the Slack Block Kit. I am not sure what is causing this issue or how to resolve it, so I am hoping to receive some guidance on Stack Overflow. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

To provide additional context on the error I am experiencing in my Slack Block Kit implementation, I am using an AWS Lambda function to handle messages from Slack. I have set up API Gateway to send requests to my Lambda function. While normal messages are being handled without issue, I am encountering an error when attempting to use the Slack Block Kit.